# SQL: How do I use only data that has a certain amount of unique combinations between two columns?

Tags: sql, group-by, count

Supposing I have three columns, make, year, and msrp, I want to only show rows there the amount of make/year combinations are over, for example, 10. This is because some makes only have data for one year and I dont want random car makes in my data.

Im able to get the number of year/make combinations for each make, but I dont know how to include other columns.
I have the query:

**SELECT make, count(DISTINCT year)**

**FROM cars**

**GROUP BY make**

which gives something like this:

```
make    | count
--------------
Honda   | 13
Ford    | 17
Bugatti | 3
...
```

but I want something like:

```
make    | count | year | msrp
----------------------
Honda   | 13    | 2001 | 100
Honda   | 13    | 2002 | 200
Honda   | 13    | 2003 | 300
Ford    | 17    | 2001 | 100
Ford    | 17    | 2002 | 200
Ford    | 17    | 2003 | 300
Bugatti | 1     | 2014 | 1000
```

and only show the rows that have a count > a number (probably 10)
* the data examples are made up *

Comment: What's the DBMS? Provide some sample data

Comment: @D-Shih Im using data.world to write the query. I put the csv here on my github for you to access https://github.com/SudeepS97/cars-csv/blob/master/cars.csv

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you don't really need `count(distinct)`.  So, to get the information:

```
select make, year, msrp,
       count(*) over (partition by make) as num_make_years
from cars;
```

If you want to filter, then use a subquery:

```
select my.*
from (select make, year, msrp,
             count(*) over (partition by make, year) as num_make_years
      from cars
     ) my
where num_make_years > 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT make, count(DISTINCT year) OVER (PARTITION BY make) "Count", year, msrp
FROM cars
GROUP BY make, year, msrp
HAVING count(make) > 10 and count(year) > 10
```

Comment: This didn't achieve what I was looking for. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: try to add over partion by